# Vim change in N item of line possible? E.g. ci2"

Tags: vim

I commonly want to change the second (or third) attribute in a string of HTML:

`<div class="Something" data-change="TOBECHANGED">Test</div>`

At present, I'm doing <kbd>f"</kbd> then <kbd>;</kbd> as needed then <kbd>ci"</kbd>. I realise I could search and replace but that's not what I'm interested in.

Then it occurred that I should be able to do something like <kbd>c2i"</kbd> (Change 2nd In "). This doesn't work - is this possible? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Comment: You can use `3f"` to go directly to the third `"`, and then use `ci"`.

Comment: Yes, that's probably better than what I'm doing currently, thanks. Is the way I'm attempting just not possible?

Comment: I don't know if what you want is possible... that's why I didn't post it as an answer, it's just a "related suggestion".

Comment: `:nnoremap <key> 3f"ci"` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With built-in commands, this is a two-step process: First locate the quotes (e.g. via `3f"`), then select them (`ci"`).

But you can make that a single-step via custom text objects. I have the following, with which you can do `c2if"`:

```
" af{c}, if{c}      a / inner [count]'th next {c} text object in the current
"           line.
" aF{c}, iF{c}      a / inner [count]'th previous {c} text object in the
"           current line.
"           For example, "dif(" would go to the next "()" pair and
"           delete its contents.
" Source: Steve Losh, https://bitbucket.org/sjl/dotfiles/src/tip/vim/.vimrc
function! s:NextTextObject( scope, isBackward )
    let l:char = ingo#query#get#Char()
    if empty(l:char) | return | endif

    let l:save_cursor = getpos('.')
    let l:direction = (a:isBackward ? 'F' : 'f')
    " Special case for "tag" text object.
    let l:findChar = tr(l:char, 't', '>')

    let l:nextTextObject = l:direction . l:findChar . 'v' . a:scope . l:char

    " To handle [count], we can't just prepend it to the f / F command, as
    " depending on the text object, there can be two identical delimiters that
    " need to be skipped (e.g. in i", but not in i[). Instead, select each text
    " object in turn, and then repeat at the corresponding border.
    let l:count = v:count1
    while l:count > 1
        let l:cursor = getpos('.')
            execute 'normal!' l:nextTextObject . "\<Esc>" .
            \   (a:isBackward ? 'g`<' . (a:scope ==# 'i' ? "\<Left>" : '') : '')
        if l:cursor == getpos('.')
            call cursor(l:save_cursor[1:2])
            execute "normal! \<C-\>\<C-n>\<Esc>" | " Beep.
            return
        endif
        let l:count -= 1
    endwhile

    execute 'normal!' l:nextTextObject
    if mode() ==# 'n'
        call cursor(l:save_cursor[1:2])
        execute "normal! \<C-\>\<C-n>\<Esc>" | " Beep.
    endif
endfunction
onoremap <silent> af :<C-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 0)<CR>
xnoremap <silent> af :<C-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 0)<CR>
onoremap <silent> if :<C-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 0)<CR>
xnoremap <silent> if :<C-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 0)<CR>

onoremap <silent> aF :<C-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 1)<CR>
xnoremap <silent> aF :<C-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 1)<CR>
onoremap <silent> iF :<C-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 1)<CR>
xnoremap <silent> iF :<C-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 1)<CR>
```

Note: This requires my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433).

Comment: Ingo, thanks, if you can update the answer just to explicitly say it's not possible with 'stock' Vim I will mark this as the answer. I think it's important for any future searchers to know off the mark it's not possible ordinarily using the method I was asking about.